# Getting copied text from Clipboard on Android 10 devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I can successfully use the below code to copy and paste from clipboard in android 9 and below devices.

To copy...

```
val clipboard = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Hello")
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

To Paste...

```
val clipboard = (getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)) as? ClipboardManager
val text = clipboard?.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text.toString()
```

Now, if I run the same in an Android 10 device, 'text' returns a null Value.

Is there something I am doing wrong?
Any Special Permissions Needed?
Or is the code different for Device running Android 10 and above?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> " If the application is not the default IME or does not have input
> focus this return null."

You aren't writing a keyboard I assume, so do you have input focus?  Particularly is there a focused element?

Comment: Hi? No, I'm not Writing a Keyboard. I am developing an application that Runs USSD. When a service operator requires input from me, a popup dialog appears with an EditText. However when I try to retrieve text copied to clipboard when focus is set to the EditText, null i return.

Comment: @CarenGarv Exactly.  The documentation says if you aren't the foreground app or the keyboard, it will always return null.  You can't use this function-  it will always return null for you.  Also I would avoid writing anything that requires USSD-  it isn't consistent between OEMs, its extremely low bandwidth, and there are no real APIs for it.  Whether it works at all or not will depend on what dialer app the user has installed.  If there is any possible alternative, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Gabe, Caren, Your comments came in Handy. I cooked a crude work around. I decided to save values needed later in a local sqlite database, and call them in my accessibility service when needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).